# Appendix not numbered - minimal document

Tags: numbering, appendices

I'm trying to put appendices in my PhD thesis, and I'd expected them to be labelled A,B, etc. However, instead it's not producing a title for the appendix at all, and it's giving me sections to my final chapter marked .1, .2 etc. I've looked around this site, and seen lots of problems about poorly placed `\backmatter` etc. but I'm getting this problem even with the following minimal code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
This is my testbed.
\appendix
\section{What's this?}
This is an appendix.
\end{document}
```

This is everything- I've not omitted any packages or anything. This produces a single page:

> Chapter 1
>
> Introduction
>
> This is my testbed.
>
> .1 What's this?
>
> This is an appendix.

I'm using TeXShop 3.39 (the latest version).

Comment: with the `book` class, the divisions after `\appendix` are expected to be `\chapter`, not `\section`.  (by the way, welcome to tex.sx.)

Comment: In the `book` class the upper level of sectioning is `chapter` as you use it in your main body - use chapter in the appendix as well to get `A`, `B` etc - and you may add `\part*{Appendix}` after `\appendix` to get a separation

Comment: I think I require a higher rep to upvote your comments, but they've solved my problem- thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The cause for this that the output for `\section` is coupled to the chapter number, i.e. 1.1 etc.

However, unless no `\chapter` is used, the result for `\thesection` should be `0.1` etc.

Now, `\appendix` redefines `\thechapter` to use uppercase letters instead of figures, so `1.1` would become `A.1`, but as the chapter number is `0`, there is no corresponding letter for this, so the output of `\Alph` is empty, leaving `.1` for the section number then.

There are some options:

- Use `\chapter` instead of `\section` in the Appendix level, as proposed by Barbara Beeton already.
- Or use `\usepackage{chngcntr}` in the preamble and `\counterwithout{section}{chapter}` after `\appendix`. This will change the section counter output too, decoupling it from `\thechapter`.

---

In the shown example I used the 2nd approach.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}

\usepackage{chngcntr}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
This is my testbed.
\appendix
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}
\section{What's this?}
This is an appendix.
\end{document}
```

[image]